# resize JFrame automatically with JPanel Java

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, jpanel

I am implementing changes to a minesweeper game. One of these things is the difficulty. I have managed to do this and its working, but as the game board (in its own Jpanel) gets bigger & smaller (depending on the difficulty), I cannot get the JFrame to resize automatically. I am using:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

to set the initial size of the window, but this makes it REALLY tiny, as in only showing the word 'File' from the JMenuBar. I have to resize it manually.

I tried setSize() and things like frame.pack() on the ActionListener event, but I cannot seem to get it to resize.

Any tips on what code/methods to use.

edit: code posted

```
package mines;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SetupFrame extends JFrame {

    private final int WIDTH = 600;
    private final int HEIGHT = 500;
    public JFrame frame;
    public JMenuBar menubar;
    public JMenu file;
    public JMenu levels;
    public JMenu help;
    public JMenuItem login;
    public JMenuItem save;
    public JMenuItem resume;
    public JMenuItem exit;
    public JMenuItem easy;
    public JMenuItem medium;
    public JMenuItem hard;
    private JLabel statusbar;
    public JPanel main;
    public JPanel buttonPanel;
    public JPanel saved;
    public JPanel game;
    public Board mineGame;
    public JButton ngButton;
    public JButton undoButton;
    public JButton redoButton;
    public JTabbedPane tp;
    public String[] levelPicker;
    public JComboBox levelSelect;
    public JFileChooser chooser;
    public String filename;

    public int difficulty;

    public SetupFrame(){

      frame = new JFrame();

      String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter Your Name.");

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setTitle("Minesweeper");

      //menubar, menus, menu items
      menubar = new JMenuBar();
      setJMenuBar(menubar);

      file = new JMenu("File");
      help = new JMenu("Help");

      menubar.add(file);
      menubar.add(help);

      login = new JMenuItem("Login..");
      save = new JMenuItem("Save..");
      resume = new JMenuItem("Resume..");
      exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

      file.add(login);
      file.add(save);
      file.add(resume);
      file.addSeparator();
      file.add(exit);

      statusbar = new JLabel("");



      chooser = new JFileChooser(); // new File Chooser for saved tab
      undoButton = new JButton(" Undo "); //undo Button for game panel 
      ngButton = new JButton(" New Game ");//new game Button for game panel
      redoButton = new JButton(" Redo");//redo Button for game panel

      main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //new panel for main game
      //main.add(mineGame, BorderLayout.CENTER); //add instance mineGame to main panel

      game = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());// new panel for game tab
      main.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER); //add the mineGames panel to game panel
      game.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //add statusbar to bottom of game panel
            //game.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH); // add buttons (eventually be redo, undo, new game)

      saved = new JPanel(); // create new panel for the saved tab
      saved.add(chooser);//add the File Chooser to the saved tab

      String[] levelPicker = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"};
      levelSelect = new JComboBox(levelPicker);
      levelSelect.setSelectedIndex(0);
            //levelSelect.addActionListener(this);

       buttonPanel = new JPanel();
       buttonPanel.add(undoButton);
       buttonPanel.add(ngButton);
       buttonPanel.add(redoButton);
       buttonPanel.add(levelSelect);
       main.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

       //create & add the tabs
       tp = new JTabbedPane();
       tp.addTab ("Game", main);
       tp.addTab ("Saved", saved);
       tp.addTab ("Statistics", null);
       add(tp);

       setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
       setResizable(true);
       setVisible(true);
       frame.pack();


        class listener implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {   
                if(e.getSource() == ngButton){
                    //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Do You want To Save");
                    newMineGame();
                }
                JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
                String picker = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
                if (picker == "Easy"){
                    difficulty = 0;
                    newMineGame();
                }
                if (picker == "Medium"){
                    difficulty = 1;
                    newMineGame();
                    frame.pack();
                }
                if (picker == "Hard"){
                    difficulty = 2;
                    newMineGame();
                    frame.pack();
                }
            }


            private void newMineGame() {
                game.removeAll();
                mineGame = new Board(statusbar, difficulty);
                game.add(mineGame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                game.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                repaint();
            }

        }

        ngButton.addActionListener(new listener());
        undoButton.addActionListener(new listener());
        redoButton.addActionListener(new listener());
        levelSelect.addActionListener(new listener());


    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SetupFrame();

    }
```

Comment: You appear to be using the right methods, but probably incorrectly. Post your code.

Comment: Additionally are you using the methods on the JPanel or the JFrame?

Comment: Using `validate();` or `revalidate();` tends to 'refresh' the JFrame/JPanel - have you tried using those?

Comment: use CardLayout as easiest of possible ways

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  See the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for a working example of resizing on PLAF change.

Comment: @mKorbel - where should I use card layout? for the different difficulty levels? or instead of JTabbedPane?

Comment: @user2777005 I am assuming I am using them on the frame as I have frame.pack();

Comment: @Ange King add all three Boards types as the Cards to CardLayout

Comment: @AngeKing : Adding a call to `pack()` as the last line (instead of repaint()), inside the `newMineGame()` method, seems to do the trick as stated by __mKorbel__. You playing with wrong references, in the code. You creating them unnecessarily like instead of using `frame.pack()` use `this.pack()`, why to create this new object of `JFrame` when the class already extends `JFrame` ?

Comment: @nIcE cOw: Thanks for the info. I updated my code as per what mKorbel advised below, but it is still not working. It obviously has something to do with the Board class, it is a Jpanel, so not sure what to do. I really didn't want to play around with GridBagLayout as it seems really complicated to me (I'm a total newb, it you couldn't already tell). Will have to do further reading :-)

Answer (score 10):

> One of these things is the difficulty. I have managed to do this and
>   its working, but as the game board (in its own Jpanel) gets bigger &
>   smaller (depending on the difficulty), I cannot get the JFrame to
>   resize automatically.

and

> tried setSize() and things like frame.pack() on the ActionListener
>   event, but I cannot seem to get it to resize.

- `JFrame.pack()` works in case

  1. that all `JComponents` representing mines (there is best of ways to use `JToggleButton`) returns properly `PreferredSize` back to its parent (`JPanel`)
  2. parent (JPanel) laid by GridLayout (very simple)
  3. and there are two ways how, when, where to `JFrame.pack()`

     - use `CardLayout`, the next code line after swithching `Card` is `JFrame.pack()`
     - remove old `JPanel` (from `JFrame`) and replace with new, then you need to call `JFrame.(re)validate()`, `JFrame.repaint()` and `JFrame.pack()` as last code lines
- maybe there is another issue, important is code ordering in the case that is there settings for `JFrame.setResizable(false);`

---

after your edit

- use [Cardlayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- there you miss code lines (don't to extends `JFrame`, create this Object as `Local variable`) `JFrame.(re)validate()`, `JFrame.repaint()` and `JFrame.pack()` as last code lines in `private void newMineGame() {`

---

> but I dont understand what you mean by: "there you miss code lines
>   (don't to extends JFrame, create this Object as Local variable) ;

code could be

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SetupFrame {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    private Board mineGame;

    public SetupFrame() {
        //there add required JComponents

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Minesweeper");
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        frame.add(mineGame);
        //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        //frame.setResizable(true);//not neccessary
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void newMineGame() {
        //remove old Board
        //add a new Board
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.pack();
    }

    private static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SetupFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I dont understand what you mean by: "there you miss code lines (don't to extends JFrame, create this Object as Local variable) ;

Comment: remove `extends JFrame` from `public class SetupFrame extends JFrame {`, because there are two `JFrame`s, one of them is never visible, and to this `JFrame` are made changes, you would need to add `frame.` before every `setXxxXxx` and `add()`, in `IDE` there are red  warnings

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes, but unfortunately, the JFrame is still not resizing :-(.

Comment: everything came from Board, remove all settings for H & W, override set/getPreferredSize for 1st. element in grid, note must be laid by Grid(Bag)Layout, then there isn't required any setting for setSize, setPreferredSize for any of its parents, e.g. JPanel, JFrame etc.

Answer (score 7):

Here is your mistake:

> `frame.pack();`

Why do you need `frame` if your `SetupFrame` actually extends from `JFrame`? Change this line by just `pack()` and it will work.

@mKorbel already posted a complete and very useful explanation about `pack()` behavior (thank you).

**Update**

Also in your `listener` class you'll get this exception when a `JButton` is pressed:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox
```

You need make this little change to avoid this:

```
class listener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == ngButton){
            //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Do You want To Save");
            newMineGame();
        } else if(e.getSource() instanceof JComboBox){ // add this else-if block
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            String picker = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            if (picker.equals("Easy")){ // <-- picker == "Easy" is not the proper way to compare string, use equals() method instead
                difficulty = 0;
                newMineGame();
            }
            if (picker.equals("Medium")){
                difficulty = 1;
                newMineGame();
                //frame.pack();  <--- again, just use pack();
                pack();
            }
            if (picker.equals("Hard")){
                difficulty = 2;
                newMineGame();
                //frame.pack();  <--- again, just use pack();
                pack();
            }
        }
    }
```

Or even better, implement an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) to listen `JComboBox` selection changes instead using an `ActionListener`

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried pack() but itself, it didn't work.  As I said, I have tried numerous things and frame.pack(); was just the last thing I tried :-)

Comment: @AngeKing Are you sure? I just did that change and it worked like a charm to me. I don't have `Board` class to test the behavior when the difficulty level changes. Please see updated answer, I found a little bug.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I changed the code, and I saw my error of adding another frame. it still doesn't resize on the change of difficulty level, so I will have a look into the ItemListener.